# How to get indices of a value in a hierarchical index series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

Suppose I have this data structure called `test`:

```
12    2     80.0
      4      2.0
      6      8.0
      7     15.0
      8     26.0
            ... 
1095  12    59.0
      15     2.0
1098  8      6.0
      13    16.0
1128  13    32.0
Length: 62, dtype: float
```

which is of type: `pandas.core.series.Series`

Now all I want is the actual coordinates of the values in the right-hand column. I.e.

```
>>>test[0]
80.0
```

Then I would like to know how I actually access the hierarchical index for this (and all other values), preferably so that it can be returned as a pair:

```
>>>test[0].method_which_returns_the_desired_indices()
(12,2)
```

And of course, the same for the rest of them i.e.

```
>>>test[2].method_which_returns_the_desired_indices()
(12,6)
```

How would one go about this? If it helps the `test` series was constructed from another pandas data frame using `stack()`.

Comment: Simply access the dataframe's indices and index them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice index with integers for positions:

```
print (test.index[0])
(12, 2)

print (test.index[2])
(12, 6)
```